# MIPS32 asm: Instruction Set Release 2 or later in QtSPIM

Tags: assembly, mips32, qtspim

Anyone knows is there QtSPIM upgrade for MIPS32 Instruction Set Release 2 or later ? Example 'ins'command.

Format: INS rt, rs, pos, size

Purpose:  Insert Bit Field
To merge a right-justiﬁed bit ﬁeld from GPR rs into a speciﬁed ﬁeld in GPR rt.

Description:

```
   GPR[rt] ←  InsertField(GPR[rt], GPR[rs], msb, lsb)
```